# Interactively pass argument and use regex in find replace

Tags: regular-expressions

I have written the following code

```
(defun krmet-replace()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion                       
  (save-restriction                     
    ;; Narrow to the region
    (narrow-to-region 
     (progn (search-forward "C %% MODULE %%")
            (line-beginning-position))
     (progn (search-forward "C %% END MODULE %%")
            (line-end-position)))

    ;; Find Replace
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "KRMET" nil t)
      (replace-match "KR23" nil t))           ;; remove the hard coded replacement, use user input
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "KR-MET" nil t)
      (replace-match "KR-23" nil t)))))       ;;;; remove the hard coded replacement, use user input

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c #") 'krmet-replace)
```

There are two things that I don not know how to do:

1. How to interactively pass a number, in this case it is "23". I want to replace `KRMET` with `KR23`. I   modified the code like shown below

```
(defun krmet-replace (r)
  (interactive "nRx # : ")
```

and used the `r` in replace match line like so

```
(replace-match (concat "KR" string(r)) nil t))
```

I get this error: `replace-match: Symbol’s value as variable is void: string`

**Answer Edit**:
I fixed the first problem like so using `number-to-string` function

```
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "KRMET" nil t)
      (replace-match (concat "KR" (number-to-string r)) nil t))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "KR-MET" nil t)
      (replace-match (concat "KR-" (number-to-string r)) nil t)))))
```

2. How to replace string using regex? Like KRMET or KR-MET with KR`nn` or KR-`nn` where `nn` is the user provided number when running the function

Comment: I think you're looking for `(format "KR-%d" r)` to convert your number into a string?  Use `%02d` if single digit numbers should have a zero prefixed.

Comment: n.b. Your question is pretty clear in general, but please never write something like "It is throwing different errors" without actually including the text of the error messages.  The error text will help others to see what the problem is.

Comment: @phils I have edited the question with the error description

Comment: Regarding the edit, note that `string(r)` isn't passing `r` to a function `string`; it's two separate expressions: `string` -- evaluating the variable `string`, and `(r)` -- calling the function `r`.  Hence the error "Symbol’s value as variable is void: string" because it turned out that `string` wasn't a variable.  As you established yourself, `(number-to-string r)` was how that should have looked.  I would still suggest using `format`, but either approach is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using `format` as well as performing both sets of replacements in a single pass by matching a regular expression:

```el
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "\\(KR-?\\)MET" nil t)
  (replace-match (format "%s%d" (match-string 1) r)
                 nil t))
```

Or adapting your concat approach:

```el
(concat (match-string 1) (number-to-string r))
```

---

Edit...

Originally I suggested the regexp `"KR\\(-\\)?MET"` which complicated things slightly for the `format` case, as `match-string` returns `nil` if the sub-group didn't match anything, and `(format "%s" nil)` returns "nil" rather than "", so I needed to use `(format "KR%s%d (or (match-string 1) "") r)` to avoid that.  Conversely `(concat "KR" (match-string 1) (number-to-string r))` was fine, as `nil` arguments to `concat` are ignored -- because in elisp `nil` is an empty list, so it's a list argument which doesn't add anything to the concatenation.

In any case, including the "KR" inside the sub-group ensures the group can't be `nil`, which simplifies things.

Using `"KR\\(-?\\)MET"` instead of `"KR\\(-\\)?MET"` would also have avoided the `nil` issue, as that would have caused the group to match the empty string when required.